# Why is Bash reporting “command not found” in some cases in the Terminal but not in others?

Tags: mac, command-line, bash, pipe, bsd

Often, but not always, when I start the Terminal on my computer and use pipe (`|`) in a command, `pbpaste | wc` as an example, bash gives `-bash:  wc: command not found`. (The double space is not a typo).

After a while, I found a solution: I removed the space after the pipe (`pbpaste |wc`) and everything worked as normal. But when I ran the pipe with the space, everything worked, and bash found the command perfectly valid, even though when I entered the exact same command a few minutes ago, it didn't like the command at all.

Here's a screenshot of this:

[image: Screenshot]

I have two, very similar, questions:

- What makes bash treat these two lines in different ways, even though there're are the same? I have no idea why this happens.
- How could I fix this?

Comment: Are you pressing Shift+space?

Comment: @grawity I don't think so, but there doesn't seem to be any difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There’s a hint to the problem in the error message; there’s an extra space showing:

```
bash:  wc: …
```

Rather than:

```
bash: wc: …
```

I assume from your question you’re using a Mac. I’m going to guess that you're using a keyboard layout in which typing the `|` character requires using the <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> key. I think that what might be happening is that you are letting your finger linger on the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key as you type the space.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> types a *non-breaking space* rather than a regular space character, which Bash’s parser does not consider to be whitespace of any sort and therefore takes as part of the command name.

It works the second time because you’re typing more carefully!